# How do you create a native bluetooth module in Android and export it to react-native?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native, android-bluetooth

I've seen creation of native modules like the android toast, but is the implementation pretty much the same when it comes to a bluetooth module that needs interaction with the hardware? I haven't found any tutorials creating a native bluetooth module for react.

Comment: Hi DeToxer, Did you find any solution?

Comment: Greetings! Yes, sort of. I managed to manually create it in Android Studio but it is not complete nor optimal. As of now I can only turn the bluetooth on/off from my ract native app. But after i added that functionality i haven't really focused on that part of the application since i had to prioritize other functionality speccs.